# Difference between a class and Abstract Data Type

Tags: java

Can any one please tell me the difference between the Abstract Data Type and Interface?
I have met with a strange problem, That is, I am unable to Differentiate Abstract Data Type and Class? Can we create a class with ADT or ADT itself is a class??

Comment: Here are some quick notes on class and interface: http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/rkirchne/cs217/tocej-proj/classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract Data Type is a general mathematical term describing an entity which has the properties that a Java class embodies (to some degree). So you can consider the Java class an example of an implementation of the ADT concept. A few relevant quotes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type):

> An abstract data type is defined indirectly, only by the operations that may be performed on it and by mathematical constraints on the effects (and possibly cost) of those operations.
>
> Abstract data types are purely theoretical entities, used (among other things) to simplify the description of abstract algorithms, to classify and evaluate data structures, and to formally describe the type systems of programming languages. However, an ADT may be implemented by specific data types or data structures, in many ways and in many programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

An ADT is an Abstract Data Type. An ADT is not implemented, it is usually a term that is used for theory and analysis. For example a Stack ADT may have the functions:

```
Push(X)
Pop()
Peek()
```

A Class is a collection of attributes/properties and functions/methods. In most Object Oriented programming languages, a class is the main way of accomplishing abstraction and inheritance.

A class for a Stack could look like:

```
public class Stack {
  private LinkedList<Integer> m_stack;  

  public Stack() {
    // some code
  }
  public void push(int item) {
    // some code
  }
  public int pop() {  
    // some code
  }
  public int peek() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

In Java, there are also `abstract class`es. These are classes that do not implement all methods. For example, we could define an abstract Stack:

```
public abstract class Stack {
  protected Collection<Integer> m_stack;  

  public Stack();
  public void push(int item);
  public int pop();
  public int peek();
}
```